# Java - LinkedList of LinkedLists of Type Object

Tags: java, object, linked-list

I am declaring a `LinkedList` of `LinkedList`s of type `GraphEdge` as follows:

First declare `LinkedList` and fixed length (for global `numVertices`):

```
LinkedList[] adjList = new LinkedList[numVertices];
```

Then initialize each `adjList[i]` as a new `LinkedList<GraphEdge>()`

```
for (i = 0; i < this.numVertices; i++) {
    adjList[i] = new LinkedList<GraphEdge>();
}
```

But I am getting an error when trying to call:

```
GraphEdge nextEdge = adjList[v].peekFirst();
```

Comment: That is not a LinkedList of LinkedLists - it's an array of LinkedLists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `LinkedList<LinkedList<GraphEdge>>` instead of an array to preserve the generic type information or add a cast.

`GraphEdge nextEdge = (GraphEdge)adjList[v].peekFirst();`

The cast is the ugly, bad solution.